# How to label image while storing as array?

Tags: numpy, opencv, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

I'm new to machine learning. I've learnt how to convert image to pixel array using numpy but how to store the label of the image simultaneously to feed for the training model? Is there a way to perform this operation for a bunch of images in one go?

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide concrete examples with intput and output

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverFlow!

We use two lists ( if you're using python ) to store the images and their labels.

```
data = []
labels = []
for i in ....:
    # some code
      data.append(var1)
      data.append(var2)
```

Suppose you have 10 images in a folder, data and labels both will have 10 entires and data[i] will correspond to label[i], i.e if data[i] is a numpy array of 255*255*3 then data[i] will be a string, say "dog".

Now there are many custom made functions used, I use the [imutils/image_paths method](https://github.com/jrosebr1/imutils#recursively-listing-paths-to-images)

But there are many other methods as well. It is advisable to go through few example codes to learn how to abstract the image labels. Generally, os.path.sep along with other python methods are used, it would be better to go through few examples